# What git command will create a feature branch based off a specific other branch, not locally but on Atlassian Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I want to find a git command that will create a feature branch, based off another specific branch (not master), on Atlassian Bitbucket and not create the branch locally.

Is there a command that would do this?

---

If I type `git branch`, I would not see the branch, because that shows only local branches.
However, if I type `git branch -a`, I would see the newly created branch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have searched and searched and have found no example to do this.

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

*All* branches are local (to the repository that you're using to view the branch names).  When using `git branch -a`, you see not just branches (which are local), but also *remote-tracking names* such as `origin/master`.

Remote-tracking names are also local (to the repository in which you are running this `git branch -r` or `git branch -a` command).  It's just that they exist *because* the Git you're using, to operate on the local repository, has seen those names in some *other* Git repository as their *branch* names, and has therefore copied them to your own Git repository, changing the names into these `origin/*` remote-tracking names instead.

So, this really boils down to the idea of having the Git on Atlassian Bitbucket create a new branch name in the Git repository stored on Atlassian Bitbucket.  There are ways to make them do that.  Some of them involve using the web interface.  These aren't Git commands, of course (but they may be more convenient than actual Git commands).  Since you've asked for Git commands, we'll ignore those ways.

In general, you can have your own Git ask any other Git to create, in that other Git repository, any name you like.  The command that does this is `git push`.  There are, however, some relatively strong constraints on how you can use `git push`, and one of those is that you literally *can't* use the *branch names* that exist in that other Git repository directly.  (This is one reason the web interface might be more appropriate.)

To ask some other Git repository to create a branch name, you *must* have *your* Git present, to that Git repository, a raw commit hash ID along with a request of the form: *create or update name _____ (fill in the blank) so that it contains hash ID _____ (fill in the blank)*.  Note that there are *two* blanks to fill in here.

To fill in those blanks, we typically run a command like:

```
git push origin xyzzy
```

where `xyzzy` is one of our own (local) branch names.  Our Git takes that branch name and converts it to a raw commit hash ID, as if we had run:

```
git rev-parse xyzzy
```

(try this command on your own branch names: `git rev-parse` is a read-only operation, so it's always safe to try on any name, or any suitable expression; see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for details).

Having converted `xyzzy` to a raw hash ID such as `a123456...` (the actual hash IDs are longer, but you can use a shortened one by using just the first four or more characters, in most cases), your Git now calls up their Git.  It fills in the raw hash ID blank from the hash ID found by your name `xyzzy`, and it fills in the name blank with `refs/heads/xyzzy`, which is the fully-spelled-out form of the branch name `xyzzy`.

Your Git knows that `xyzzy` *is* a *branch* name—as opposed to, say, a tag name like `refs/tags/v2.3`—because `xyzzy` is a *branch* name in *your own* repository.  So your Git turns this request, which has just one branch name on your side, into a request that has a branch name on each side.  It uses the *same* name on *their* side for sanity's sake (in all normal and sane setups anyway: there are some unusual or crazy setups where this might not be the case; there really are some reasons to get wild and crazy, sometimes, though it's best to avoid such situations if at all possible).

Now, you don't actually *need* a branch name.  If you know the right hash ID, you can use the full `git push` *refspec* syntax like this.  Suppose you'd like to ask them to create their branch name `xyzzy`, and you don't have a *name* for commit `faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475`, but you *do* have commit `faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475` in your repository.  Then:

```
git push origin faefdd61ec7c7f6f3c8c9907891465ac9a2a1475:refs/heads/xyzzy
```

sends that same kind of *create or update name _____ so that it contains hash ID _____* request, with the name coming from the right hand side of the colon, and the hash ID from the left.  *You must spell out the full name* because they (presumably) do not have `xyzzy` yet and they won't know if this should be a branch, or a tag, or something else entirely.  Spelling it out as `refs/heads/xyzzy` tells them *this is a branch name* so that they can proceed to use it.

The true constraints, then, to creating a branch in some other Git repository are these:

- The commit you'd like them to set their branch name to, must exist in your own repository.
- You must have permission to create new branch names via `git push`.

(Git itself lacks this sort of permissions system, so that if you've set up your own Git server, you will in general just have these permissions.  But GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, and other hosting services invariably add on some sort of permissions control structure.  The absence of one would send too many customers to their competitors, who do offer these control structures: GitHub raised that bar long ago.)

Now, using a big ugly hash ID like this is a pain.  Fortunately, there's no need to go through all that pain.  Simply run:

```
git fetch origin
```

first if necessary, to obtain all the commits *from* the Git over at the Atlassian site.  This will also obtain all their *branch* names, and use those to create or update your own *remote-tracking names* in your own Git repository.  So if they now have a branch named `plugh`, you now have `origin/plugh` in *your* Git repository, along with the appropriate commit.  You can now run:

```
git push origin origin/plugh:refs/heads/xyzzy
```

to create, in their Git repository, the branch name `xyzzy`, pointing to the same commit as the commit you have in your Git repository as found by the name `origin/plugh`, which—at least as of a few seconds ago—was the commit you wanted.  The drawback to this method is those few seconds: by now, `plugh` might have changed by dozens or hundreds of commits, depending on how fast new commits are coming in to the Git repository over there.  But even using their web interface does not really help much here, because if there are 50 new commits coming in on `plugh` every second, then by the time you have them create `xyzzy` from their `plugh` and you can sit back and look at it, 50 or 100 new commits will be in their `plugh`.

---

The short version of all of the above is that what you're looking for is possible, but is pretty pointless.  There's nothing special about branch names.  There's no real reason to create one in *their* repository without also creating one in your own.  Just create a branch, do the work, and *then* create the name in the other Git repository based on the commits you've already constructed locally.